# How to model a CLI client in Python

Tags: python, command-line-interface, router

I need to provide a Python client to represent a CLI of a Cisco router. The requirement of such a client is that it allows auto-complete of the commands inside PyCharm.

For example, if a developer wants to call the CLI command:

```
commit confirm <commit_confirm_time> log <log>
```

The developer can type

```
commit.confirm.
```

and get a list of the auto-complete values:

```
.log(log='log.txt')
commit_confirm_time('aaaa')
```

because

```
cli.commit.confirm.log(log='log.txt')
cli.commit.confirm.commit_confirm_time('aaaa').log('file1.log')
```

stand for

```
commit confirm log <log>
commit confirm <commit_confirm_time> log <log>
```

---

I wrote this short code to model a specific family of commands, but the full set is 5000+ unique permutations of commands, so I am looking for a better way to model the commands while keeping the requirement of allowing to auto-complete the commands

```
from typing import List

    commands: List[str] = ['commit log <log>',
                           'commit no-warning',
                           'commit and-exit log <log>',
                           'commit check log <log>',
                           'commit check no-warning',
                           'commit confirm log <log>',
                           'commit confirm <commit_confirm_time> log <log>',
                           ]
    
    
    class CliLog:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
    
        def log(self, log=''):
            pass
    
    
    class CliAndExit:
        def __init__(self):
            pass
    
        def log(self, log=''):
            pass
    
    
    class CliCheck(object):
        def __init__(self):
            pass
    
        def log(self, log=''):
            pass
    
        def no_warning(self):
            pass
    
    
    class CliConfirm(object):
        def __init__(self):
            self.log: CliLog = CliLog()
    
        def log(self, log=''):
            pass
    
        def commit_confirm_time(self, commit_confirm_time='') -> CliLog:
            return self.log()
    
    
    class CliCommit:
        def __init__(self):
            self.and_exit: CliAndExit = CliAndExit()
            self.check: CliCheck = CliCheck()
            self.confirm: CliConfirm = CliConfirm()
    
        def log(self, log=''):
            pass
    
        def no_warning(self):
            pass
    
    
    class Cli:
        def __init__(self):
            self.commit: CliCommit = CliCommit
    
    
    cli: Cli = Cli()
    
    cli.commit.log('file1.log')
    cli.commit.no_warning()
    cli.commit.and_exit.log('file1.log')
    cli.commit.check.log('file1.log')
    cli.commit.check.no_warning()
    cli.commit.confirm.log(log='log.txt')
    cli.commit.confirm.commit_confirm_time('aaaa').log('file1.log')
```

Comment: You could use https://typer.tiangolo.com/ which provides completion.

Comment: Thanks @CarlosHorn. This tool looks interesting. In my case the CLI already exists. I am looking to provide auto-complete capabilities for developers in PyCharm. I will update the question to better reflect it.